# Linq let and if

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting:

> Non-static method requires a target.

The problem is that `Status` is null. I don't understand why, because there is a condition which clearly indicates if `Status` is null return `1`.

```
var filterstatus = (from bq in basequery
                    let LastStatus = Status == null ? 1 
                              : ((from sd in ems.SampleDatas
                                where sd.Reference_id == Status.id 
                                     && sd.DateTimeUTC <= bq.DateTimeUTC
                                orderby sd.DateTimeUTC
                                select ((sd.Value >= StatusValue) ? 1 : 0)
                                      ).DefaultIfEmpty(1).FirstOrDefault())
                    select new { bq, LastStatus });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's converting the entire expression into SQL, and not doing the short-circuit in memory (the short circuit would be handled by the database).

You can write something like this, which will properly short-circuit in the database (but still generate the right hand side of the query).

```
var statusID = Status == null ? (int?)null : Status.id;

var filterstatus = (from bq in basequery
    let LastStatus = 
        statusID == null ? 
        1 : 
        ((from sd in ems.SampleDatas
            where sd.Reference_id == statusID && sd.DateTimeUTC <= bq.DateTimeUTC
            orderby sd.DateTimeUTC
            select ((sd.Value >= StatusValue) ? 1 : 0)
      ).DefaultIfEmpty(1).FirstOrDefault())
    select new { bq, LastStatus });
```

Ideally, though, you'd have two separate queries, depending on `Status`, as it's already known at that point whether the right hand side is required or not.

Comment: @Zulander No worries :)